# Automated Employee sickness tracker

Tags: workflow

I have been messing around with Sharepoint lately and wanted to start a new project.
I am an HR administrator for an American company in Germany. Our employees are required to call us if they cannot make it to the shift because of sickness, so my team can inform their managers accordingly.
We are using excel sheets right now where we collect all calls and then send mails to the managers manually once the big swing of calls stops. One of the main problems is that we all work on separate sheets and need to combine them once we are ready to send the mails out to the supervisors.
We also want to automate the emailing process.
I visited another branch and saw that the HR Admins had a Sharepoint where they pretty much just needed to type in the personal id and duration of absence which triggered a workflow pulling all necessary data like name, department, manager and so on and send emails automatically out their respective managers.
Sadly the colleagues could not provide us any help because that was a project from their local IT and the person who set up the Sharepoint left the company.
If I recall correctly the Sharepoint utilized 2 lists. One containing the actual absence record created after each call by entering the personal id and absence duration into a form and one list with an employee report updated manually once every few weeks.

I would appreciate any help or links to tutorials. Also sorry for any mistakes, english is obviously not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question, I understand you would like a SharePoint to make easier your job. But you directly talk about the lists and automation of process required to accomplish your needs. But, what about the topology of the installation? and version? You must first know that. You can use an on-premise option (install SharePoint on your local servers) with a 2013 Foundation, which is free. Or you maybe wish a 2016 Server or Enterpise, which is paying for licenses and it has more functionalities. Or you maybe use Office 365 in your company, and you can use SharePoint Online, so it would be just to develop the functionalities and not install anything. I mean, this kind of question before starting :)

Here you have some articles explaining the differences:

- [SharePoint On-Premises vs SharePoint Online: The Breakdown](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-on-premises-vs-sharepoint-online)
- [What are the differences between SharePoint versions & Office 365](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/differences-sharepoint-versions-and-office365)
- [SharePoint 2013 vs 2016](https://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013-vs-2016/)

About your question, it doesn't seem complex, rather, it seems easy. It would be to create some lists, and with a simple workflow send some emails, but you must first know how.

I give you some links so you can see how to do it more or less:

1. [Create a list in SharePoint 2013/2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-list-in-sharepoint-0d397414-d95f-41eb-addd-5e6eff41b083)
2. [How to Create SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow](https://blog.virtosoftware.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/)

Comment: Hi Sergio, good point! Our company uses on premise SharePoint 2016. And thanks for the links you provided, I will definitely have a look and see if I can achieve what I intend to do :-)